# How can I request to merge two tags?

Tags: support, tags

I've noticed two tags being used for the same purpose on Stack Overflow.

Is there a place where I can request a fix?

Comment: Yes, on [Stack Overflow's own meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: so, the anwser is no.... =/

Answer (score 2):

As Glorfindel commented, meta is the place to do it. Only Mods and CMs can make that edit so make sure you give enough information so the merge or synonym request can be reviewed (by the community as well as mods, because despite looking like the same usage, there may be other reasons to have them)

Similarly for other sites, just ask in the site meta.